Is there any way to capture composite video through microphone port?
I was wondering if there would be any way to use the 3.5mm microphone port on my PC to capture Composite/RCA/AV video through?
It seems like it'd work in theory, since composite video and 3.5mm AUX are basically the same, just a different connector type, and I have an RCA to 3.5mm cable.
But I don't know how I would get that out of the microphone port.

They are not "basically the same."
They might be analogue signals, but that is where their similarity ends.
Composite video has a bandwidth of a few MHz and the signals are highly complex operating at a high frequency.
Audio signals are at most 20kHz, we use 48kHz or 96kHz for sampling because to accurately read a 20kHz signal you need to sample at 2 or more times that signal frequency. See Nyquist Frequency.
Audio recording electronics will be tuned for accurate sampling of low frequencies, not the high frequencies used by composite video.
You absolutely cannot capture composite video using a microphone port. They require completely different approaches in their signal capture.

Exactly. A composite signal generally has a bandwidth of 4.5 MHz, 200 times wider than audio. The analog-to-digital converter (ADAC) in a PC can easily handle 20 kHz, not 4.5 MHz. One could try slow-scan video, http://www.arrl.org/sstv-slow-scan-television, and get a frame every few seconds... Or, hey, there's fax.

No, they are not the same, and they are also not compatible.
Yes, they are the same SHAPE, a 3.5mm diameter segmented metal connector, but the composite AV connector will have 4 segments, and the microphone will have at most 3, if it accepts stereo audio input (if it only accepts mono input it will only have two segments).
Next, the microphone input port is likely directly connected to the audio subsystem on your mainboard, and that system will thing every bit of data coming over it is audio data and will treat it as such.
What you imagine will only work if:

The routing of leads from the microphone input port is routable.
The microphone input port is actually compatible with the Composite A/V connector (it can connect the correct number of segments).
Probably other requirements too.

